# Wordpress - Dashboard not allowing to Customize Header Logo

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, customization

I have [adaptive flat theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/adaptive-flat) there in the Dashboard i have the option to customize the theme i.e., Header Logo

But it doesn't show me the options I don't know reason

Here is my Screen

**Screen which shows the option**

[image]

**Screen which shows the options not showing.**

Note :

Even i uninstalled the them , deleted and newly installed the theme and did the same in another folder too, cleared the cache and cookie but it is not succesfull

I even navigated to main page, sub page in the left pane but i can't able to see the header edit option to update the header logo.

**How can i get back ??**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In adaptive-flat/lib/customizer.php put the following code:

```
//header image

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'header_logo' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'Header Logo', 'giga_flat' ),
    'priority'   => 2,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_image' , array(
    'default'     => '',
    'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_image', array(
    'label'        => __( 'Image Upload', 'giga_flat' ),
    'section'    => 'header_logo',
    'settings'   => 'header_image',
    'priority' => 2, 
    ) ) );
```

Comment: I added, but still not use, (Its behaving like old, its appearing and disappearing in seconds like old)

Comment: If the code is in place then be sure you use the last version of the theme. It might be a setting issue not a technical one. It is hard to say without an example.

Comment: ahm, yes i will upload the files in live and will convey you.. (I have the last theme only :) )